# In SharePoint after site creation site is not Opening ?its throwing IIS error why?

Tags: sharepoint-server

In my SharePoint 2013 after creating web application and site creation the site is not opening and its throwing following error.Why its happening,please someone help for this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have any custom solution deployed into your farm?

Comment: yes i was deployed solution from visual studio.

Answer (score 2):

Did you make any manual changes to the web.config file? Looks like there is safe control entry in web.config file that is causing the error (in your screenshot the line that is highlighted). The safe control line is not correct and probably also not in the correct node. Try removing that line from web.config file.

Comment: I was removed that line now it was working,But manually i did not change anything in web.config then why its coming like this ?If you know pls share with me

Comment: i shared screenshot above in that web.bak files are there.this files are generated in only my system, in my colleague system only web.conf file is there.

Comment: .bak file is generated everytime the web.config is updated. It is just a backup of the file so you can have a look or revert back to an older version.